# Probability and moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $x$ be a random variable, s.t. $E(x)=0$.

Why is the condition $m^4P(|x|\geq m)=o(1)$ equivalent to the boundedness of the 4-th moment of variable $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not* equivalent: if $Y$ is a non-negative random variable, existence of the $p$-th moment is equivalent to the convergence of $\int_0^\infty \mathbb t^{p-1}P(Y\geqslant t)\mathrm dt$.

We can take a symmetric random variable $X$ such that for $t\geqslant 0$,
$$\mathbb P(X\geqslant t)=C\cdot \frac 1{t^4\log t},$$
where $C$ is a normalizing constant.

However, we can check that the existence of the fourth moment implies the condition on $\mathbb P(|X|\geqslant t)$. Indeed, replacing $X$ by $X^4$, it's enough to prove that if $Y$ is integrable then $u\mathbb P\{|Y|\geqslant u\}\to 0$ as $u\to \infty$. To see that, notice that $\int |Y|d\mathbb P\geqslant \sum_{k\geqslant 1}k\mathbb P\{k\leqslant |Y|\lt k+1\}$, hence the series $\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb P\{|Y|\geqslant k\}$ is convergent. Since the sequence $(\mathbb P\{|Y|\geqslant k\})_{k\geqslant 1}$ is non-increasing, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you. But hoe to check now that the existence of the 4-th moment implies the condition? Just a Chabychev's inequality?

Comment: We need some sharper bounds, see edit.